# Python Socket Substitute Variable for hostname

Tags: python, sockets

I have tried various ways to substitute a variable for the hostname into socket.connect call, but I can't get it to work.  I am doing the substitution b/c I want to read a list of host IPs from a file and connect to each of them.  I have the variable properly formatted as a string with single quotes around it, but it won't connect:

```
# Connect to the Servers LOOP
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f1:
        for server in f1:
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            server = server.strip('\n')
            server = "'%s'" % server
            print 'Connecting to ' + server

            #connect=s.connect(('10.11.1.229',25))
            connect=s.connect((server,25))

            # Receive the banner
            banner=s.recv(1024)
            print banner

            s.close
```

If I hard-code the hostname, it works fine.  Execution results in:

```
Connecting to '10.11.1.8'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./connect-loop.py", line 19, in <module>
     connect=s.connect((server,25))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Appreciate any assistance...

Comment: remove the single ticks `server = "%s" % server` or the double ticks `server = '%s' % server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add ticks to the server name (I guess, in order to properly format it when printing it), which are then interpreted when resolving the hostname.

Try with:

```
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f1:
    for server in f1:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        server = server.strip('\n')
        print 'Connecting to {} ...'.format(repr(server))

        connect=s.connect((server,25))

        banner=s.recv(1024)
        print repr(banner)

        s.close()
```

Changes:

- Format the hostname directly in the `print` line, and use `repr` to quote it.
- Remove the uneeded hostname formatting line
- Add missing parenthesis to the `close()` at the end.

Note about `repr`: it returns the "human representation" of the given value, which, for a string value, is the same string quoted.

Comment: That was it.  The original problem was just the '\n' in the rows I was reading in.  I had then added in the ticks as part of that troubleshooting.   Should have cleaned that up.  Thanks!